# How to link a Python script to React Native app

Tags: python, python-3.x, react-native, expo

I'm developing a react native application using Expo, it will display different data, preprocessed and cleaned with Python, along with sentiments analysis on tweets regarding a specific topic.

What is the best way to do that? I read about using RESTful API with Flask but after some reading I don't think it will serve this purpose.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an AWS lambda endpoint for sending data and retrieving the processed results. With the free tier of AWS lambda you get "...1M free requests per month and 400,000 GB-seconds of compute time per month."

Seems like it might suit your use-case.

Tutorial you can easily follow along with here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/aws_lambda/aws_lambda_function_in_python.htm

Some more info on setting up a rest API using lambda:
https://blog.sourcerer.io/full-guide-to-developing-rest-apis-with-aws-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda-d254729d6992

Reference for AWS lambda free tier here:
https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a totally new information. If the data is only preprocessed once, do you think it is efficient to just run the script once and export the data to files and then just read them from the react native application?

Comment: If you think you might run the same procedure on the same data, and it will yield the same results, it probably makes sense to cache the result using app storage.